# How to give the security permissions to delete file from my sdcard in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

How to give the permissions to delete a file from SDCARD. Following code is working on simulator but in the phone, It's not working. How to solve my problem?

```
FileConnection fileConnection1=(FileConnection)Connector.open("file path");
fileConnection1.setWritable(true);
fileConnection1.delete();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can request permissions from the person running your application but you may not forcefully set them so you need to gracefully handle your request being rejected.

The API involved is [ApplicationPermissionsManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2.1api/net/rim/device/api/applicationcontrol/ApplicationPermissionsManager.html)

I suggest you look at and possibly use this [sample code](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-Invoke-a-Permissions-request-with-other-applications-also/ta-p/652397) (depending on which OS versions you are supporting) because there are a few quirks also explained at this [url](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-Invoke-a-Permissions-request-with-other-applications-also/ta-p/652397).

The exact permission you are looking for might be: `ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_FILE_API`

But I suggest you check the versions you are developing against for deprecation as several permissions have been retired or changed names over the years.